# AuroraRDS Serverless with data-api library in Java does not work

Tags: java, maven, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora

I want to access a database via the data-api which is AWS providing since the start of 2020.

This is my Maven code (only aws dependency shown):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.790</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.rdsdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>rds-data-api-client-library-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my Java code

```java
public class Opstarten {

    public static final String RESOURCE_ARN = "arn:aws:rds:eu-central <number - name >";
    public static final String SECRET_ARN = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:<secret>";
    public static final String DATABASE = "dbmulesoft";
       
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        new Opstarten().testme();

    }
    
    public void testme( ) {
        
        var account1 = new Account(1, "John");  //plain POJO conform AWS manual hello world example
        var account2 = new Account(2, "Mary");
        
        RdsDataClient client = RdsDataClient.builder().database(DATABASE)
                .resourceArn(RESOURCE_ARN)
                .secretArn(SECRET_ARN).build();
        
        client.forSql("INSERT INTO accounts(accountId, name) VALUES(:accountId, :name)").
        withParameter(account1).withParameter(account2).execute();
    }
}
```

Error I am having:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.amazon.rdsdata.client.RdsDataClient.executeStatement(RdsDataClient.java:134)
at com.amazon.rdsdata.client.Executor.executeAsSingle(Executor.java:92)
at com.amazon.rdsdata.client.Executor.execute(Executor.java:77)
at nl.bpittens.aws.rds.worker.Opstarten.testme(Opstarten.java:47)
at nl.bpittens.aws.rds.worker.Opstarten.main(Opstarten.java:29)

When I debug it I see that the client object is nog null but the rdsDataService is null as a method or parameter of the client object.
I have checked AWS side for Java RDS Data API but nothing is mentioned there.

Any idea whats wrong ?

Comment: Hi, I allready found the problem. I am approaching this RDS Serverless via a public IP. In the AWS RDS serverless manuals is stated that  RDS by design is not public accessable.

Comment: In your example its not setup as a public accessible your accessing it through a secret arn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you aren't passing RDS data service, you need to do as follows:

```
AWSRDSData awsrdsData = AWSRDSDataClient.builder().build();
RdsDataClient client = RdsDataClient.builder()
                        .rdsDataService(awsrdsData)
                        .database(DATABASE)
                        .resourceArn(RESOURCE_ARN)
                        .secretArn(SECRET_ARN)
                        .build();
```

You can also configure mapping options as follows:

```
 MappingOptions mappingOptions = MappingOptions.builder()
                                 .ignoreMissingSetters(true)
                                 .useLabelForMapping(true)
                                 .build();
 AWSRDSData awsrdsData = AWSRDSDataClient.builder().build();
 RdsDataClient client = RdsDataClient.builder()
                                .rdsDataService(awsrdsData)
                                .database(DATABASE)
                                .resourceArn(RESOURCE_ARN)
                                .secretArn(SECRET_ARN)
                                .mappingOptions(mappingOptions)
                                .build();
```

Comment: When I try with version 2.0.0 it looks like `RdsDataClient` no longer has the methods that are described here and I don't see any alternative.

Comment: Should be there in 2.0 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.rdsdata</groupId>
   <artifactId>rds-data-api-client-library-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>`

Check this link :  
  
[AWS Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.calling)